# I need to post a collection of objects from knockout js foreach binding in my asp.net mvc4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, knockout.js

I need to post a collection of objects from knockout js foreach binding in my asp.net mvc4 application.
Below is my foreach loop in knockout

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "SystemParameters", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>@ViewBag.Title</h4>
        <hr />

        <div style="width: 50%;" data-bind="foreach:gm.systemparameters.systemparameterCollections">

                <div style="width: 30%; float: left; padding: 15px 2%;">
                    <span data-bind="text:Name"></span>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 65%; float: left;">
                    <input type="text" data-bind="text:Value">
                </div>

    </div>
    <div style="width: 100px; padding-left: 560px;">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" style="height: 40px; width: 110px; margin-top: 2px; " />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

and in my post method, i am getting null in the model

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Collection<SystemParameterViewModel> model)
    {
        try
        {
```

How can I get the collection of edited objects in model?

Comment: For `ìnput` elemnts, you should use the `value` binding not `text`:`<input type="text" data-bind="value:Value">`.

Answer (score 1):

Your generated inputs must have names that the modelbinder can work with to build your model after POST. Currently, you don't have any names at all on the inputs within the Knockout foreach, so of course you're getting no data. Based on the parameter your POST action accepts, your inputs need to have names in the form of:

```
name="[N].PropertyName"
```

Where N is the position in the collection. You can use the special variable `$index` to get the current index of your foreach loop:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Value, attr: { name: '[' + $index + '].Value' }">
```